# open feign does not recognize static headers

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-11, openfeign

I have tried dynamic headers sending them as HashMap like this:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("x-country", "CL");
```

and all works fine, but I need to send them as static headers, and I am doing it this way:

```
//feign client interface:
@FeignClient(name = "ms-enterprise-api", url = "http://localhost:8082")
public interface ApiFeignClient {
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/v1/msService/getData", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json","x-country: CL"})
    ResponseEntity<PayResponseDTO> getVoucher(@RequestBody PayRequestDTO request);
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/v1/msService/getData", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<PayResponseDTO> getVoucherOld(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headerMap, @RequestBody PayRequestDTO request);
    
}
```

The error I get in the API requested:

> feign.FeignException$BadRequest: [400] during [POST] to
> [http://localhost:8082/v1/...getData]
> [ApiFeignClient#getVoucher(PayRequestDTO)]:
> [{"timestamp":"2022-09-02T14:33:57.360+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad
> Request","trace":"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException:
> Required request header 'x-country' for method para... (6239 bytes)]

Am I doing something bad?